# Can the property $z^*z\in [0,\infty)$ be generalized to other fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, involutions

Let $K$ be a field equipped with the following structure:

1. Let $*$ be an involution $*:K\to K,z\mapsto z^*,$ where $*$ preserves field structure and $(z^*)^* = z$ for all $z\in K$.
2. Assume that $z^*z\in[0,\infty)$ for all $z\in K$.

Two well-known structures satisfy these properties: $\mathbb R$ (with the identity map) and $\mathbb C$ (with complex conjugation). Any subfields of these examples should also work. **Are there any other examples?**

---

Background: This property is crucial for defining the inner product over $\mathbb C$-vector spaces, and I am interested in generalizing inner products to vector spaces over other fields. But if no other "interesting" fields satisfy this property, then there isn't much point to this effort.

Comment: When you write $[0,\infty)$, do you mean specifically the subinterval of $\mathbb R$, or generally the set of non-negative numbers of a suitable ordered subfield of $K$?

Comment: @celtschk I meant the subinterval of $\mathbb R$, as this is necessary in order to make contact with the $\mathbb R$ that appears in definitions of a norm and metric space.

Comment: I think you are looking for formally real fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any field that fulfils your conditions is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb C$.

Proof:

First, note that obviously $z^*z\in K$, and your condition 2 implies that lso $z^*z\in\mathbb R$. Therefore $R:=K\cap\mathbb R$ is nonempty. Indeed, it is not hard to show that it is a field, too. Which in particular means that is is a subfield of $\mathbb R$. Since in particular $R$ is ordered, this also implies that $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$. This is important because it allows us to divide by $2$; I'll make use of that in the following. Also, since $R\subseteq\mathbb R$, it inherits the order of $\mathbb R$; this means we can compare elements in $R$.

Now let's take the fact that $z\mapsto z^*$ is an involution. If $z=z^*$ I'll call $z$ symmetric, if $z=-z^*$, I'll call it antisymmetric. This allows us to define a symmetric and an antisymmetric part as
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{symm}(z)&=\frac12(z+z^*)\\
\operatorname{asym}(z)&=\frac12(z-z^*)
\end{eqnarray}
so that $z=\operatorname{symm}(z)+\operatorname{asym}(z)$.
Note that in the complex numbers, the symmetric part is the real part, and the antisymmetric part is $\mathrm i$ times the imaginary part.

Now if $z=s+a$ where $z$ is symmetric and $a$ is antisymmetric, we
have
$$z^*z = (s+a)^*(s+a) = s^*s + s^*a + a^*s + a^*a = s^2 - a^2$$

Now let's define the set of symmetric elements, $S=\{z\in K: z=z^*\}$. It is not hard to check that it is a subfield of $K$, let's call it the symmetric subfield.

But that means that $S$ is a field in which the square of any element is a positive real number. Since the real numbers contain all the square roots of all the positive real numbers, this implies that $S$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb R$.

Without loss of generality, in the following we can assume $S\subseteq R$. That is, we can decompose any $z\in K$ into a real number and an antisymmetric element of $K$. But for antisymmteric elements of $K$ we have
$$(a^2)^* = (a^*)^2 = (-a)^2 = a^2$$
therefore the square of an antisymmetric element is symmetric, and therefore a real number. Moreover we have seen above that $-a^2$ is positive, therefore $a^2$ is negative. Thus the antisymmetric elements of $K$ square to negative real numbers. But that is exactly what the purely imaginary numbers do. Therefore we can map the antisymmetric elements to the imaginary numbers.

But that means that, up to isomorphism, every element of $K$ is the sum of a real number and an imaginary number, that is, a complex number.

And this means that $K$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb C$.

**Note:** I've explicitly used the requirement stated in the comments to the question that the interval from condition $2$ is indeed the real interval. If it were not required to be the real interval, then other solutions would exist.

Comment: This does not satisfy (2), although it will if you replace $2$ by $-2$ but in that case it's just the restriction of complex conjugation.

Comment: Your expression should be $a^2 - 2b^2$ so for instance $z=1+\sqrt 2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @TokenToucan: Oops, you're right.

Comment: @TokenToucan: I've now replaced the answer.

Comment: I think this is false too. Consider the field $K=\mathbb F_{2^2}$ with its automorphism $\tau$ of order 2 over $\mathbb F_2$ and identify $\mathbb F_2$ with the set $\{0,1\}$ in $\mathbb R$. Then $K$ and that automorphism satisfy the conditions of the question. This of course generalizes to any other extension of degree 2 of finite fields. If you restrict how $K$ can intersect $R$ by forcing it to be in a subfield then maybe it works like you say.

Comment: No, it doesn't. No subset of $\mathbb F_{2^2}$ is also a subset of $\mathbb R$ (don't get confused by the same symbol being used for the neutral elements in both fields; in $\mathbb F_{2^2}$ you have $1+1+1+1=0$, in $\mathbb R$ you don't. In particular, on no subset of $\mathbb F_{2^2}$ you can define an order, therefore even if the interval were not meant to be the real interval (which the OP stated in the comments it is), you'd not be able to even define the interval to begin with. Note that I explicitly used the requirement that the interval is the one of the real numbers.

Comment: Yes, I can choose to identify a subset with $\mathhbb R$. One can build a copy of $\mathbb F_4$ on any $4$-element set. Obviously the ring maps are not going to be compatible.

Comment: @TokenToucan: If you don't demand compatibility of the operations, then the identification is meaningless, and condition 2 does nothing but constrain the cardinality.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific about what I mean by $z^*z\in[0,\infty)\subseteq K$, but to be honest I'm not exactly sure. I want the inner product axiom $\langle x,x\rangle\geqslant 0$ to make sense, and ultimately I want the inner product to induce a norm.

Comment: @celtschk I agree and certainly the "morally" correct answer has to be yours. The "counterexample" just indicates that relaxing your extra restriction on (2) makes the whole question rather vacuous, which I think is good information.

Comment: It's probably cleanest to refine my condition (2) to say that the "symmetric subfield" described above should have an embedding in $\mathbb R$. But then I worry if there are multiple possible embeddings and no canonical choice of how to identify $[0,\infty)$ with $\{z^*z\}$.

Comment: At any rate, I'm still going through these answers but I find both to be quite interesting because they show what is and isn't possible, depending on how we interpret $[0,\infty)\subseteq K$

Comment: @WillG: If you want to get a proper norm, I think you need to settle with the interval to be a subset of $\mathbb R$, as that is how norms are defined. However you might settle for an “almost-norm” by just requiring that $S$ is an ordered field. In that case, $F_{p^2}$ won't work (finite fields are never ordered), but for example hypercomplex numbers.

Comment: @WillG: Or actually, you probably don't even need that $S$ is ordered, just that $\{z^*z:z\in K\}$ is subset of an ordered subfield of $K$.

Comment: @celtschk Suppose there were some interesting field whose elements $\{z^*z\}$ were very naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Say, a field whose elements are sequences $\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N},a_i\in\mathbb R$, and that $\{z^*z\}$ turns out to be the set of sequences where all but the first element is zero. Thus there is a natural isomorphism with $\mathbb R$. Ideally we could include cases like this, right?

Comment: @celtschk I also considered restrictions like your previous suggestion, but I think we also need to worry about excluding non-archimedean fields like the hyperreals, which are ordered but certainly not what we want.

Comment: @WillG: [Every archimedean ordered field is isomorphic to a subfield of the reals.](https://planetmath.org/ArchimedeanOrderedFieldsAreReal)

Comment: @celtschk I think to properly generalize my condition (2), I should say $P=\{z^*z|z\in K\setminus\{0\}\}$ is the positive part of an ordered archimedean subfield of $K$. Then there is a canonical embedding of $P$ into $[0,\infty),$ if I understand correctly. I think your answer still applies in this case, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example. Fix a prime $p$. Let $K = \mathbb F_{p^2}$ and $\sigma$ the order $2$ automorphism of $K$ over $\mathbb F_p$, so the involution is $z^* = \sigma(z)$. Identify $\mathbb F_p$ with $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$ in $\mathbb R$ so that we can talk about its intersection with $\mathbb R$.

Then this clearly satisfies $(1)$ and $(2)$ - for $(2)$ just notice that $zz^*$ is the norm from $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ to $\mathbb F_p$ and so it lands in $\mathbb F_p$ which we have selected to be in $[0,\infty)\subseteq \mathbb R$.

If you put restrictions on how $K$ and $\mathbb R$ can intersect, then it seems very likely that you will just end up with subfields of $\mathbb C$ as the other answer explains. Condition (2) strongly biases your fields towards this case. I would think about replacing it by requiring the fixed field of the involution to be an ordered field and that $zz^*\geq 0$ according to that ordering. Even that I don't think is optimal e.g. it won't work in the $p$-adic setting, but that is a pretty interesting place to study vector spaces and analysis and so on.

Edit: to clarify a misunderstanding on the comments to another answer, I do not claim that the identification of $\mathbb F_p$ with $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$ preserves or has anything to do with the ring properties, as it certainly cannot (e.g. for characteristic reasons). This is just purely at the level of sets so that, as explained above, one can even talk about an intersection with $\mathbb R$ for the purposes of treating (2) in the question.